# displaying multiple columns value in look up edit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

i am a look up edit box containing following fields.

### S.no    Name

1           vinoth

2           kumar

form the look up drop down box if i select 1st row(1    vinoth),
then my lookupedit display the value as "1 - vinoth"

can any 1 tell me how to do.

Comment: What do you want to happen after you select 1st row?

Comment: if i select 1st row the the look up edit should display 1- vinoth

Comment: Do you have two columns in your lookupEdit (one numeric and the other is a string) ? Is the value (1 - Vinoth) the result of a concatination of the 2 columns of the selected row ?

Comment: yes 1 col is int another one is string

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use three columns 
1.S.No
2.Name
3.Combination of S.No and Name as you want

and then set column three as Display member

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public List<UserInfo> mylist = new List<UserInfo>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mylist.Add(new UserInfo() { Id = i, Name = "Name" + i, Description = "Description " + i });
    }
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = mylist;
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```